# Revisited: zero-length matches in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I was looking at this question from last year: [Zero-length matches in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906471/zero-length-matches-in-java-regex):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ababa");
while(matcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.start()+"["+matcher.group()+"]"+matcher.end());
}
```

produces the output:

```
0[a]1
1[]1
2[a]3
3[]3
4[a]5
5[]5
```

I'm wondering if this is correct.  The pattern matches either "a" or an empty string.  When the Matcher is pointed at the first "b", there's no "a" so find() matches the empty string.

However, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) says:

> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.

So when the Matcher is pointed at 'b', no characters are matched and find() matches an empty string, which means that after that, the first character not matched by the previous match (i.e. the empty string) will still be 'b'.  That should mean that the next find() should start at the same place, according to the above, which would mean that the code should loop infinitely.  But of course that isn't what's happening.  It looks like it just bumps the starting point up by 1 when an empty string is matched.

So what's up?  Is the implementation wrong, or did the javadoc leave something out, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, "b" does not match "a?". That's clear from the output 1[]1, the start and end are the same, so it's the empty match. However, the find() in that case has consumed "b". The question ajb is asking is why does find() ever progress forward in this case. The answer is that the matched group is different than the matched region (try also printing matcher.regionEnd()).

Comment: It still doesn't make sense.  After it matches the first "a", it's pointing at 'b'.  Then the second find() returns the empty string, and according to the JLS the matcher should still be pointing at 'b' for the next find(), since 'b' was not matched by the second find().  So it looks to me like the matcher should be in the same state before the second find(), as before the third find() ... but something about it is different since it's returning a different result.  regionStart() and regionEnd() don't change, either (and they're only changed by region(), I think).  So what's different?

Answer (score 1):

`a?` means *zero or one 'a' characters*, so it will match an `a` or a "nothing" - it's matching the "a" chars and "nothingness" positioned *between* the "a" and "b" characters.

This is completely correct and expected.

Comment: It is correct, but lacks one important _extra_ detail.  By default, regex is configured to be greedy, which means it will expand to match the largest pattern possible.  So, even though `0[]0` should be in the match list, it won't get reported because `0[a]1` is the larger match, at the same indexes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it does look like there's a special case when find() returns an empty string.  To make things clear, since I think some didn't understand the question, my issue was why the matcher state should be different before the second find() and before the third find(), since the "first character not matched by the previous match" will be the same in both cases.

The difference is that the bounds of the previous match are stored in the matcher's state, and they *do* affect the next find(), but only in this one case.  From the find() code in Matcher.java:

```
 int nextSearchIndex = last;
 if (nextSearchIndex == first)
      nextSearchIndex++;
```

`last` is where the search is going to start, unless the last find() returned an empty string (or `first` or `last` is set by some other method), and then it moves up one.  There's no comment on this snippet, so I'm not sure what the purpose was, but it looks like it was intentionally making a special case of an empty string match.  It does seem to contradict the javadoc, though, since in this one case the search starts in a place other than where the javadoc says it does.

EDIT: By the way, this does have a consequence that may look surprising:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a?");
 Matcher m = p.matcher ("abcde");
 m.find();
 System.out.println("[" + m.group() + "]");
 m.find();
 System.out.println("[" + m.group() + "]");
 m.usePattern (Pattern.compile("[bd]"));
 m.find();
 System.out.println("[" + m.group() + "]");
```

outputs

```
[a]
[]
[d]
```

The last match doesn't find "b", even though the 'b' character has not been matched by any previous match and shouldn't have been skipped over.  It's a bit obscure, though.